# Stanford NLP parsers and idioms that have common semantic meaning

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, linguistics

I have parsed the following sentence in the [Stanford CoreNLP demo page](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process) and the [Stanford parser demo page](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp). Although both result in a parse that can imply purpose semantics (hinging on the `advcl` and the `sbar` accordingly), clearly the parsers don't capture "in order to" as an expression whose meaning much transcends the relationships between its own word constituents (as in an idiom).

`he went to the shop in order to buy food`

What kind of parsing, or pre-processing stage, may yield "in order to" as a single unit of meaning, thus making it amenable to semantics derivation same as a preposition affords? e.g. "for" may commonly imply purpose semantics, and having "for" parse as a preposition assists in deriving purpose semantics.

Answer (score 0):

As it currently stands, Stanford NLP does not allow this short of forking the code and fixing one nasty bug with your bare hands.